# Python metaprogramming paradigm - is there a 'standard'?

Tags: python, metaprogramming

I am trying to get my arms around the idiom - if there is one - related to Python metaprogramming.  This comes up, for example, with serializers.

For example, the Django REST framework points out you would be tempted to do something like this, which seems straightforward:

```
from datetime import datetime

class Comment(object):
    def __init__(self, email, content, created=None):
        self.email = email
        self.content = content
        self.created = created or datetime.now()

comment = Comment(email='leila@example.com', content='foo bar')like
```

However, with little explanation, they then show how it is done in their 'idiom', as I will call it, and it looks like this:

```
from rest_framework import serializers

class CommentSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
    email = serializers.EmailField()
    content = serializers.CharField(max_length=200)
    created = serializers.DateTimeField()
```

I get lost on why one would not have the code look more like this, as it is purely a design choice:

```
class CommentSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
    self.email = serializers.EmailField()
    self.content = serializers.CharField(max_length=200)
    self.created = serializers.DateTimeField()
```

with some appropriate getter/setter functions.

I have actually looked at the source code, and can't identify if there is a method to the madness.  When instantiated, a 'comment' based on this approach involves endless introspection using magic methods (to see what was declared in the class), lots of byzantine code shaped like:

```
class ListSerializer(BaseSerializer):
    child = None
    many = True

    default_error_messages = {
        'not_a_list': _('Expected a list of items but got type "{input_type}".'),
        'empty': _('This list may not be empty.')
}

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.child = kwargs.pop('child', copy.deepcopy(self.child))
        self.allow_empty = kwargs.pop('allow_empty', True)
        assert self.child is not None, '`child` is a required argument.'
        assert not inspect.isclass(self.child), '`child` has not been ins tantiated.'
        super(ListSerializer, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.child.bind(field_name='', parent=self)

    def bind(self, field_name, parent):
        super(ListSerializer, self).bind(field_name, parent)
        self.partial = self.parent.partial

    def get_initial(self):
        if hasattr(self, 'initial_data'):
            return self.to_representation(self.initial_data)
        return []
```

This code is so dense as to be nearly impossible to decipher.

My question is really is this just a one-off that works, or is there a pattern here that is useful to master and replicate? I have a hard time seeing a larger paradigm or idiom.  If anything, there seems to be a very byzantine use of introspection, metaclasses, and dynamic methods to accomplish an outcome that is stylized, but pretty hard to understand how to use the approach more generally.

Comment: Can you be more specific about what the idiom is? Give examples of what you're talking about? Even so, this may not be a good question for the Stack Overflow format.

Comment: The [help/on-topic] says you can't ask us to recommend or find an off-site resource. See the section with the numbered list, in particular item #4 in that list.

Comment: OK - I have clarified the question, but it is now a lot longer....

Comment: Do you understand the difference between instance and class methods/attributes?  self.foo implies that this is an instance attribute; just foo implies it is a class thing

Comment: Yes, I do.  It seems to me that - in the case of serializers - you end up with a class-wide instance that 'describes' the data chunk.  Then, when you go ahead and instantiate an object using that class, it gets an instance attribute for each of those that conforms to that class-wide descriptor (itself a class).   This, then, means that (1) a single dynamic change could percolate through all instances, and (2) more to the point, it is very hard to see how to do this all well without a uniform cookbook.  I am sure the serializers all work, but it is a pretty messy template to follow.

Comment: This is just how DRF chooses to use metaclasses, following the way Django chooses to use metaclasses for models. There’s no language standard. You haven’t provided a real alternative, though – that sample code wouldn’t run, and if you extended it to a complete one you might notice it’s incredibly painful. And does it make the implementation of `ListSerializer` any easier? It’s best to look at these as a DSL for something along the lines of `comment_serializer = Serializer([… fields …])` instead… which is what they are, except as a type instead of something implementing `serialize`.